# How to Make Nested Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for

I want to make a nested form step by step between two models , has_one
The nested form should make me able to choose options from one of the models and save it into the other one

Comment: I know But it didnt get me clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My most favorite tutorial on Nested Form.
Here is the railscast tutorials. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: thanks , and I don't know what scaffold is , is it something to create a form instead of form_for ? , can i use form_for instead of it ? . I followed Michael Hartl's tutorial and he didn't use a scaffold when he created a sign up page, sorry for that stupid question but I need someone to explain that for me ! and I hate reading articles :D Can you explain it for me please ?

Comment: ok, `scaffold` is a great technique of Rails to generate Model, View and Controller just using one single command. Say, you want to create an User. Just run `rails generate scaffold user`. This command create a `User` model, a `user_controller' and a view (app>view>user). For this scaffolding, some generalized or basic actions are created in controller automatically and also view for each action. It's really easy and fun to create application in Rails. :)

Comment: so `scaffold` is instead of creating a Model then creating a Controller and i can use the same syntax , thats all, am i right ?

Comment: scaffold generates Model,View and Controller at once. You can also able to generate only model, or only controller, or only view using `rails generate model/controller/view user`

Comment: aha so the base of the form i may use scaffold to generate it , after that the other Models will be generated by typing `rails generate Model` , right ?

Comment: no no, if you run `rails generate scaffold user` it's creates all Model, View and controller, no need to run `rails generate model` or `rails generate view` again.

Comment: I mean if i havei want to make Country model , then a country has many States ? so i should generate two Models (Country , State) to add them into the form , right ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `fields_for` ;)

See the documentation here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for